# settings view controller not dismissing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm making a task list application that has 2 simple view controllers... I embedded a navigation controller in the first(**HomeScreen**), however, the next view controller (**Settings**) isn't dismissing when I hit my custom back button. Do I have to set up my Home View Controller as the root VC? Then use `popToRootVIewController` Method? I've been using `dismissViewControllerAnimated`...

**Settings View Controller implementation file:**

```
//
//  AGSettingsViewController.m
//  QuickList3
//
//  Created by Alex Gartenberg on 4/11/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 A.Gartenberg. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AGSettingsViewController.h"

@interface AGSettingsViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *backgroundTitleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fontTitleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *settingsTitleLabel;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL fontColor;
@end

@implementation AGSettingsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set title of view
    self.settingsTitleLabel.text = @"SETTINGS";

    // Determine background color
    if (!BACKGROUND)
    {
        self.settingsBackgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        // Retrieve image wrapped in NSData
        NSData *imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:BACKGROUND];
        // Unwrap the image from NSData
        UIImage *savedBackground = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        // Set image as new background
        self.settingsBackgroundImage.image = savedBackground;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Back Button Method

- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self didSaveSettings];
    NSLog(@"Back Button Pressed");
}

#pragma mark - NSUserDefaults Persistance

-(void)saveSettings
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    //Select current background
    UIImage *savedBackground = self.settingsBackgroundImage.image;

    //Wrap image in an NSData Object
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(savedBackground, 100);
    //Save Data wrapped Image Object to NSUserDefaults
    [defaults setObject:imageData forKey:BACKGROUND];

    //Font Color Bool Saved
    [defaults setBool:self.fontColor forKey:FONT_COLOR];

    //Persist Data
    [defaults synchronize];
}

#pragma mark - AGSettingsViewController Save and Dismiss

-(void)didSaveSettings
{
    [self saveSettings];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you shouldn't use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` as it will only affect view controllers presented modally by their parents.
I'll agree that [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW103) could be clearer about this, albeit this line should have hinted that this couldn't work (emphasis mine):

> The top-most view is dismissed using its **modal** transition style

So to remove the top view controller from the `UINavigationController`'s stack, you must use

```
-(void)didSaveSettings
{
    [self saveSettings];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Ok that worked to remove the view controller, however, now my Home View Controller is not showing up. I'm just getting a blank screen. Does this have something to do with prepare for segue? Do I have to instantiate a new view controller for the home VC?

Comment: Nope, you shouldn't have to do anything special. But reading your question, I'm not sure you set up the HomeScreen controller correctly. `UINavigationController` should be the main vc, and embed the HomeScreen view controller (either by using `initWithRootViewController:` or the `viewControllers` property). If you are using storyboard (but it don't seems to be the case) it is simpler even.

Comment: @GuilliaumeAlgis Do you have any links where I can check to see if I set it up correctly, since I did not use either `initwithRootViewController` or the `viewController` property. I actually did set everything up in storyboards, but 'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/. You could also create a new project in Xcode with the "Master-Detail" template to have a reference of a `UINavigationController` laid out in a storyboard.